# Get relative path from comparing two absolute paths

Tags: python

Say, I have two absolute paths. I need to check if the location referring to by one of the paths is a descendant of the other. If true, I need to find out the relative path of the descendant from the ancestor. What's a good way to implement this in Python? Any library that I can benefit from?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

[os.path.commonprefix()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) and [os.path.relpath()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) are your friends:

```
>>> print os.path.commonprefix(['/usr/var/log', '/usr/var/security'])
'/usr/var'
>>> print os.path.commonprefix(['/tmp', '/usr/var'])  # No common prefix: the root is the common prefix
'/'
```

You can thus test whether the common prefix is one of the paths, i.e. if one of the paths is a common ancestor:

```
paths = […, …, …]
common_prefix = os.path.commonprefix(list_of_paths)
if common_prefix in paths:
    …
```

You can then find the relative paths:

```
relative_paths = [os.path.relpath(path, common_prefix) for path in paths]
```

You can even handle more than two paths, with this method, and test whether all the paths are all below one of them.

**PS**: depending on how your paths look like, you might want to perform some normalization first (this is useful in situations where one does not know whether they always end with '/' or not, or if some of the paths are relative).  Relevant functions include [os.path.abspath()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and [os.path.normpath()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath).

**PPS**: as Peter Briggs mentioned in the comments, the simple approach described above can fail:

```
>>> os.path.commonprefix(['/usr/var', '/usr/var2/log'])
'/usr/var'
```

even though `/usr/var` is *not* a common prefix of the paths.  Forcing all paths to end with '/' before calling `commonprefix()` solves this (specific) problem.

**PPPS**: as bluenote10 mentioned, adding a slash does not solve the general problem. Here is his followup question: [How to circumvent the fallacy of Python's os.path.commonprefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498939/how-to-circumvent-the-fallacy-of-pythons-os-path-commonprefix)

**PPPPS**: starting with Python 3.4, we have [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#), a module that provides a saner path manipulation environment. I guess that the common prefix of a set of paths can be obtained by getting all the prefixes of each path (with [`PurePath.parents()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents)), taking the intersection of all these parent sets, and selecting the longest common prefix.

**PPPPPS**: Python 3.5 introduced a proper solution to this question: [`os.path.commonpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath), which returns a valid path.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks for your prompt answer. Will accept your answer once the time restriction is lifted.

Comment: Take care with `commonprefix`, as e.g. the common prefix for `/usr/var/log` and `/usr/var2/log` is returned as `/usr/var` - which is probably not what you'd expect. (It's also possible for it to return paths that are not valid directories.)

Comment: @PeterBriggs: Thanks, this caveat is important.  I added a PPS.

Comment: @EOL: I don't really see how to fix the problem by appending a slash :(. What if we have `['/usr/var1/log/', '/usr/var2/log/']`?

Comment: @EOL: Since I failed to find an appealing solution for this problem I though it might be okay to discuss this sub-issue in a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498939/how-to-circumvent-the-fallacy-of-pythons-os-path-commonprefix).

Comment: That's the most postscripts I've ever seen. Thanks for keeping the answer up to date

Answer (score 131):

[`os.path.relpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

> Return a relative filepath to path either from the current directory or from an optional start point.

```
>>> from os.path import relpath
>>> relpath('/usr/var/log/', '/usr/var')
'log'
>>> relpath('/usr/var/log/', '/usr/var/sad/')
'../log'
```

So, if relative path starts with `'..'` - it means that the second path is not descendant of the first path.

In Python3 you can use [`PurePath.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to):

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:54:32)
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> Path('/usr/var/log').relative_to('/usr/var/log/')
PosixPath('.')

>>> Path('/usr/var/log').relative_to('/usr/var/')
PosixPath('log')

>>> Path('/usr/var/log').relative_to('/etc/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/pathlib.py", line 851, in relative_to
    .format(str(self), str(formatted)))
ValueError: '/usr/var/log' does not start with '/etc'
```

Comment: Checking for the presence of `os.pardir` is more robust than checking for `..` (agreed, there are not many other conventions, though).

Comment: Am I wrong or is `os.relpath` more powerful since it handles `..` and `PurePath.relative_to()` does not?   Am I missing something?

Comment: @RaySalemi is correct, it should be noted that `>>> Path('/usr/var').relative_to('/usr/var/log')` fails with a `ValueError`

Answer (score 22):

A write-up of jme's suggestion, using pathlib, in Python 3.

```
from pathlib import Path
parent = Path(r'/a/b')
son = Path(r'/a/b/c/d')            
​
if parent in son.parents or parent==son:
    print(son.relative_to(parent)) # returns Path object equivalent to 'c/d'
```

Comment: So `dir1.relative_to(dir2)` will give PosixPath('.') if they are the same. When you use `if dir2 in dir1.parents` then it excludes the identity case. If someone is comparing Paths and wants to run `relative_to()` if they are path-compatible, a better solution may be `if dir2 in (dir1 / 'x').parents` or `if dir2 in dir1.parents or dir2 == dir1`. Then all cases of path compatibility are covered.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is

```
>>> print os.path.relpath('/usr/var/log/', '/usr/var')
log
```

Comment: This always return a relative path; this does not directly indicate whether one of the paths is above the other (one can check for the presence of `os.pardir` in front of the two possible resulting relative paths, though).

Answer (score 4):

Pure Python2 w/o dep:

```
def relpath(cwd, path):
    """Create a relative path for path from cwd, if possible"""
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        cwd = cwd.lower()
        path = path.lower()
    _cwd = os.path.abspath(cwd).split(os.path.sep)
    _path = os.path.abspath(path).split(os.path.sep)
    eq_until_pos = None
    for i in xrange(min(len(_cwd), len(_path))):
        if _cwd[i] == _path[i]:
            eq_until_pos = i
        else:
            break
    if eq_until_pos is None:
        return path
    newpath = [".." for i in xrange(len(_cwd[eq_until_pos+1:]))]
    newpath.extend(_path[eq_until_pos+1:])
    return os.path.join(*newpath) if newpath else "."
```

Comment: This one looks good, but, as I stumble upon, there is an issue when `cwd` and `path` are the same. it should check first if those two are the same and return either `""` or `"."`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** See jme's answer for the best way with Python3.

Using pathlib, you have the following solution :

Let's say we want to check if `son` is a descendant of `parent`, and both are `Path` objects.
We can get a list of the *parts* in the path with `list(parent.parts)`.
Then, we just check that the begining of the son is equal to the list of segments of the parent.

```
>>> lparent = list(parent.parts)
>>> lson = list(son.parts)
>>> if lson[:len(lparent)] == lparent:
>>> ... #parent is a parent of son :)
```

If you want to get the remaining part, you can just do

```
>>> ''.join(lson[len(lparent):])
```

It's a string, but you can of course use it as a constructor of an other Path object.

Comment: It's even easier than that: simply `parent in son.parents`, and if it is, getting the remainder with `son.relative_to(parent)`.

Comment: @jme You answer is even better, why don't you post it?