# How to remove a path prefix in python?

Tags: python, string, path, prefix

I wanted to know what is the pythonic function for this :

I want to remove everything before the `wa` path.

```
p = path.split('/')
counter = 0
while True:
    if p[counter] == 'wa':
        break
    counter += 1
path = '/'+'/'.join(p[counter:])
```

For instance, I want `'/book/html/wa/foo/bar/'` to become `'/wa/foo/bar/'`.

Comment: Fyi, when dealing with paths better use the split/join functions from the `os.path` module

Answer (score 239, accepted):

A better answer would be to use os.path.relpath:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath

```
>>> import os
>>> full_path = '/book/html/wa/foo/bar/'
>>> relative_path = '/book/html'
>>> print(os.path.relpath(full_path, relative_path))
'wa/foo/bar'
```

Comment: This is a much better answer because it avoids any issues with different path separators.

Comment: Totally agree with @intrepidhero's comment, plus this works whether or not `full_path` contains the trailing `/` character or not—so it's even more general than that.

Answer (score 42):

For Python 3.4+, you should use [pathlib.PurePath.relative_to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to).
From the documentation:

```
>>> p = PurePosixPath('/etc/passwd')
>>> p.relative_to('/')
PurePosixPath('etc/passwd')

>>> p.relative_to('/etc')
PurePosixPath('passwd')

>>> p.relative_to('/usr')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 694, in relative_to
    .format(str(self), str(formatted)))
ValueError: '/etc/passwd' does not start with '/usr'
```

Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287996/python-get-relative-path-from-comparing-two-absolute-paths) for more answers to your question.

Comment: While the `pathlib` module is very "user friendly", it wasn't created until very late in the game. Personally I still prefer using `os.path.relpath()` as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19856910/355230) because it will work in most versions of Python (including Python 2).

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> path = '/book/html/wa/foo/bar/'
>>> path[path.find('/wa'):]
'/wa/foo/bar/'
```

Comment: +1: compared to using a regular expression, this is simpler, and probably about as fast.

Comment: This returns the last character if the string doesn't contain `/wa` (`path[-1:]`), so if that might happen you'd want to check `if "/wa" in path` first

Comment: alternately, you can use `str.index` instead of `str.find` to raise an exception when the needle is not in the haystack.

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple folders of same names.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

path = '/book/html/wa/foo/bar/'
m = re.match(r'.*(/wa/[a-z/]+)',path)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: This helps for my second question which was how to remove the last path if it is a integer. Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new string functions called .removeprefix and .removesuffix in Python 3.9 and later.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0616/

These built-in functions behave like the following

```
def removeprefix(self: str, prefix: str, /) -> str:
    if self.startswith(prefix):
        return self[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return self[:]

def removesuffix(self: str, suffix: str, /) -> str:
    # suffix='' should not call self[:-0].
    if suffix and self.endswith(suffix):
        return self[:-len(suffix)]
    else:
        return self[:]
```

this does not directly remove it per the question but if you know the full prefix it can be a help.