# Common path between filenames (like in git)

Tags: python, path

I noticed that git commit has a fancy way of showing source/destination path in a regex-like way, for example:

```
wallpapers/{8.jpg => 1.jpg}
```

Is there any Python module that produces this kind of "shortenage"? For example, I would expect something like:

```
/home/user/doc.pdf => /home/user/Desktop/doc.pdf
```

turned into

```
/home/user/{doc.pdf => Desktop/doc.pdf}
```

or perhaps even

```
/home/user/{ => Desktop}/doc.pdf
```

another example from git

```
{deprecated => deprecated code}/Binary.cs
```

Comment: You need to be more specific when you say `"shortenage"`. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to [How to circumvent the fallacy of Python's os.path.commonprefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498939/how-to-circumvent-the-fallacy-of-pythons-os-path-commonprefix/21499676#21499676) can be modified to produce this result:

```
def commonprefix(l):
    # this unlike the os.path.commonprefix version
    # always returns path prefixes as it compares
    # path component wise
    cp = []
    ls = [p.split('/') for p in l]
    ml = min( len(p) for p in ls )

    for i in range(ml):

        s = set( p[i] for p in ls )         
        if len(s) != 1:
            break

        cp.append(s.pop())

    return '/'.join(cp+['{'+' => '.join('/'.join(p[i:]) for p in ls)+'}'])

print commonprefix(['wallpapers/8.jpg','wallpapers/1.jpg'])
print commonprefix(['/home/user/doc.pdf', '/home/user/Desktop/doc.pdf'])
```

Prints:

```
wallpapers/{8.jpg => 1.jpg}
/home/user/{doc.pdf => Desktop/doc.pdf}
```