# How to find the relative path between two directories?

Tags: python

I would like to find the relative path between two directories on my system.

**Example:**

If I have `pathA == <pathA>` and `pathB == <pathA>/dir1/dir2`, the relative path between them will be `dir1/dir2`.

How could I find it in python? Is there a tool I could use?

If **pathB** is contained in **pathA**, I could just do `pathB.replace(pathA, '')` to get this relative path, but what if **pathB** isn't contained in **pathA**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory)

Comment: @mescalinum The answer of this post is a pythonic answer but the question was for bash.

Comment: top answer of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory) is in python

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, but not the question.

Comment: But now there are posts that could be almost the same, I agree. Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287996/python-get-relative-path-from-comparing-two-absolute-paths I didn't find before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`os.path.relpath(path1, path2)  # that's it`

Comment: I already tried, but I still have to wait 4 minutes before this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `relpath()` function of the `os` module.

```
import os

os.path.relpath(pathA, pathB)
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html),

> os.path.relpath(path[, start])
>
> Return a relative filepath to path either from the current directory
>   or from an optional start directory. This is a path computation: the
>   filesystem is not accessed to confirm the existence or nature of path
>   or start.