# How can I remove a prefix from a filename in Python?

Tags: python

I want to write a script that receives a path to a directory and a path to a file contained in that directory (possibly nested many directories deep) and returns a path to this file relative to the outer directory.

For example, if the outer directory is `/home/hugomg/foo` and the inner file is `/home/hugomg/foo/bar/baz/unicorns.txt` I would like the script to output `bar/baz/unicorns.txt`.

Right now I am doing it using `realpath` and string manipulation:

```
import os

dir_path = "/home/hugomg/foo"
file_path = "/home/hugomg/foo/bar/baz/unicorns.py"

dir_path = os.path.realpath(dir_path)
file_path = os.path.realpath(file_path)

if not file_path.startswith(dir_path):
    print("file is not inside the directory")
    exit(1)

output = file_path[len(dir_path):]
output = output.lstrip("/")
print(output)
```

But is there a more robust way to do this? I'm not confident that my current solution is the right way to do this. Is using startswith together with realpath a correct way to test that one file is inside another? And is there a way to avoid that awkward situation with the leading slash that I might need to remove?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `commonprefix` and `relpath` of the `os.path` module to find the longest common prefix of two paths. Its always preferred to use `realpath`.

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.realpath("/home/hugomg/foo")
file_path = os.path.realpath("/home/hugomg/foo/bar/baz/unicorns.py")
common_prefix = os.path.commonprefix([dir_path,file_path])

if common_prefix != dir_path:
    print("file is not inside the directory")
    exit(1)
print(os.path.relpath(file_path, dir_path))
```

Output:

```
bar/baz/unicorns.txt
```

Comment: This also feels off... lstrip treats its parameter as a set of characters to remove, not as a prefix to remove. And does this still work if `dir_path` and `file_path` are not normalized, absolute path names?

Comment: perhaps `relpath` is more suited?

Comment: Looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287996/python-get-relative-path-from-comparing-two-absolute-paths/7288019#7288019) is close to what I was asking. BTW, someone there pointed out that apparently commonprefix is deprecated in favor of the commonpath function.