# Is there a python function to replace absolute urls with relative url paths?

Tags: python, relative-url

I'm crawling a website and saving selected pages for offline browsing.  Of course the links between pages are broken so I'd like to do something about that.  Is there a somewhat simple way in python to relativize url paths like this without reinventing the wheel:

```
/folder1/folder2/somepage.html    becomes---->   folder2/somepage.html
/folder1/otherpage.html           becomes---->   ../otherpage.html
```

I understand the function would need two url paths to determine the relative path as the linked resource's path is relative to the page it appears on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Get relative path from comparing two absolute paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287996/python-get-relative-path-from-comparing-two-absolute-paths)

Answer (score 0):

the newer `pathlib` (only briefly mentioned in the duplicate) also works with urls:

```
from pathlib import Path

abs_p = Path('https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html')
rel_p = abs_p.relative_to('https://docs.python.org/3/')
print(rel_p)  # library/pathlib.html
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks promising, however I forgot to mention that I'm using python 2.7 because that is the version installed on mac osx and I want this to be portable.  If nothing else, I might have a look at the source code and pick the bits that I need assuming the source works in 2.7.