# dynamic way to find relative paths from absolute paths in python

Tags: python, path, relative-path, pathlib

I have a list of absolute paths that I would like to turn to relative paths in order to insert into a script that imports files.

```
# minimum example

current_directory = os.getcwd()
parent_parent_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
absolute_path = '/Users/Documents/projects/packout_model/data/03june2022/validated_packout_2015_2021.xlsx'

# relative_path = .... # relative path for validated_packout_2015_2021.xlsx is what we would be looking for.
```

I have come across some good examples for getting a relative path, but I have not been able to find a way to always get the correct relative path from an absolute path and a current working directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287996/get-relative-path-from-comparing-two-absolute-paths